# include a page (having data) into another page which haven't that data supplied by any controller cause variable undefined issue in codeigniter

Tags: php, include, codeigniter-3

I have left_sidebar.php file where i have echo all the left_sidebar.php content through variable $content, after including left_sidebar.php in index.php file through php include ('left_sidebar.php'), the issue here is that the variables $content that i have used in left_sidebar.php file causing issue of undefined on index.php view.

Controller

```
public function LeftSidebarData()
{
    $url1 = 'url to pick the data';
    $curl_hand = curl_init($url1);
    curl_setopt($curl_hand, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($curl_hand, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($curl_hand, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data1 = curl_exec($curl_hand);
    curl_close($curl_hand);
    $content['searchingtype'] = (array) json_decode($data1,true);

    $this->load->view('left_sidebar.php',$content);

}
```

This controller is providing data to left_sidebar.php file correctly.
but My problem is when i include this left_sidebar in index.php as include(left_sidebar.php) file it gives undefined variable searchingtype on line 20 left_sidebar.php.

here is my index.php code:

Comment: Cool. And now tell us the question and show your code.

Comment: I have controller with a method that provide data to left_sidebar page, the variable used in left_sidebar page not working in index.php page where i have included this left_sidebar through include ('left_sidebar.php').

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before asking questions please read [\[ How to ask minimal, complete, verifiable example \]](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 0):

First of all on view page

`print_r($searchingtype)`

`exit`;

and execute the code.So you can get what data pass in view

Thanks

Comment: $this->load->view('left_sidebar.php',$content);

print_r($searchingtype);exit; page left_sidebar.php, It's print data correctly on this page my problem is when i include(left_sidebar.php) in any other (in my case i have include left_sidebar.php in index.php page) page then it gives undefined variable $searchingtype.
Priyanka Sankhala

Comment: You can't direct include ` include(left_sidebar.php)` like this if you want to add this page into other view you need to follow complete method   

$content['searchingtype'] = (array) json_decode($data1,true);

$this->load->view('left_sidebar.php',$content);

$this->load->view('other_page.php');

Comment: yes currently i have same method that you have mention but the method i am trying to do will be good for minimality and 'dry' code.
thanks for your reply.